# yii2 search in gridview encrypted data (searchModel)

Tags: search, encryption, yii2

Little question, i had to encrypt the "name" field in my table... but, i need to be able to do a searrch with the gridview... 
And this, does not work :

```
query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->decryptData($this->name)]);
```

Just to say, i have a decryptData() and encryptData() in my model. The encryption/decryption works everwhere, just not on the filter.

if i do

```
query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->encryptData($this->name)]);
```

i don't get any result in the gridview even without any search

any idea how to search in encrypt data ?

Thank you very much !

EDIT: 
@MuhammadOmerAslam @MichalHynčica , 
this what i do in my model :

```
  public function encryptData($data){
      $secretKey = '23jks2k4js82kj';
      $encrypted = utf8_encode(Yii::$app->security->encryptByKey($data, $secretKey));
      $key = $encrypted;
      return $key;
    }

    public function decryptData($data){
      $secretKey = '23jks2k4js82kj';
      $decrypted = Yii::$app->security->decryptByKey(utf8_decode($data), $secretKey);
      $key = $decrypted;
      return $key;
    }
```

i need to be able to type for example : Vir and that the rows with Virginie, or Virginia, or Viridontknowwhat will show.

Whould it be possible to decrypt the datas in an array, then search in it ?

or would it be better to do a search with jQuery on the gridview as the datas are decrypted in the gridview ? 
I was trying this but can't stop the gridview to send the datas to the searchModel.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: i think you are using a like on encrypted data which wont work,as the `name` has the encrypted data saved, above all what are you encrypting it with ? you can only compare with an `=` if you are not decrypting the column data at the time of comparing with the incoming query string.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam if the encrypted value is stored as string (eg. in hexadecimal or base64 format) the `like` condition should still work for exact match. As long as his `encryptData` returns same cipher text each time it's called with same argument.

Comment: @MichalHynčica i was talking about the first one `query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'name', $this->decryptData($this->name)]);` as he is decrypting instead of encrypting

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam first query is completely wrong. Since he is talking about gridview search `$this->name` probably contains data from request. So this line takes open text in `$this->name`. Then it tries to decrypt it resulting in some gibberish data. Then it's compared to encrypted data stored in DB.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam  i've edited my question :)

Comment: @MichalHynčica  i've edited my question :)

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam how could i do this :  "if you are not decrypting the column data at the time of comparing with the incoming query string. "

Comment: @DavidP The `yii\base\Security::encryptByKey()` is nondeterministic. That means that every time you do `$this->encryptData()` you will get different string even if you are encrypting same name. This is because there is random initialization vector generated each time and then the IV is stored as part of ciphertext. You have 3 options how to deal with it. 1) Buy commercial licence of DBMS, they usually have some encryption support so you won't need to implement it. 2) Load id & name for all rows, decrypt and search each time. 3) Build your own search index and store it encrypted as whole.

Comment: If you want to turn off GridView's automatic filtering try setting `$filterOnFocusOut` property of GridView to `false`.